# Глубокое копирование объектов

Tags: javascript

```
function cloneanddeep () {
    for (let key1 in obj) {
        cloneobj[key1] = obj[key1];
        if (typeof obj[key1] === `object`) {
            for (let key2 in obj[key1]) {
                cloneobj[key1][key2] = obj[key1][key2]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу написать функцию глубокого клонирования объектов. Ничего не выходит. cloneobj.size и obj.size - ссылки на один и тот же объект.

Comment: естественно -  `cloneobj[key1] = obj[key1];`

Comment: `cloneobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: а без метода json и применения фреймворков никак иначе не получится?